# xlCategory error in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a graph that has dates on the x-axis with minimum and maximum values using Excel VBA.

```
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Data").Range("A5:A202")

minimum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
maximum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Initiation").Chart
    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = minimum
        .MaximumScale = maximum
    End With
    With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MinimumScale = 0
        .MaximumScale = 100
    End With
End With
```

The second internal "With" using "xlValue" works fine.

The first internal "With" using "xlCategory" causes a runtime error: Method "MinimumScale" of object "Axis" failed.

I cannot figure out what the problem is.  Does anyone know what is is?

Thanks much.

Comment: What is the exact chart type? Does it have at least one series plotted?

Comment: It is a line graph.  I have been working on 11 separate series for the chart.  The chart has the correct series names in the legend.  The Y axis is created.  The data for all the series exists but is not connected yet.  Was trying to get the x axis done so chart would know which goes where.

Answer (score 0):

Correct these lines accordingly

```
Dim minimum As Double: minimum = Cdbl(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng))
Dim maximum As Double: maximum = Cdbl(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng))
```

As per your code, the method fails because of the type mismatch. `minimum` and `maximum` are declared without `Dim` which makes them variant rather than double datatype and your method according to MSDN is Read/write **Double**.

Add `Option Explicit` in your VBA editor so that you will get a compiler error rather a runtime error. This means that you will alerted if there is a missing `dim`.

Add `Option Explicit` only once in your code. It has to be outside outside of your subroutines.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I added your changes (which cleaned up my code) but it still complains on the MinimumScale.  I tried changing the code to use 0 and 100 instead of minimum and maximum and it still complains.

Comment: Undeclared variables are of type `Variant`, not `Object`

Comment: @RalfTassman Paste you entire code then.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes variant correct it

Comment: But that is not the cause of the problem - as long as the assigned values are numeric then it should raise no error. In any case, the return values from Min/Max are Doubles: try (eg) `Debug.Print TypeName(minimum)`

Comment: Changed from Variant to Double.  Debug.Print TypeName(minimum) comes up as double.  I tried Debug.Print "xlValue: " & TypeName(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(activeObjs).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 100).  This comes up as boolean.  Using xlCategory in place of xlValue throws an error.